# AWS CloudWatch Insights query field with hyphen in name

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Trying to run CloudWatch Insights query containing `reqHeaders.x-forwarded-for`, like

```
fields @timestamp, status, err, method, url, req_id, reqHeaders.x-forwarded-for
| filter status >= 400
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 10
```

but this field is always empty despite it was properly parsed in `@message`. I suspect this is because of hyphens in subfield name. Does anybody know how to re-format the query to get it displayed?

EDIT: here is a log message sample (pure JSON, I just formatted it)

```
{
    "cache": null,
    "client": "172.31.10.31",
    "component": "server",
    "err": "Invalid access token",
    "hostname": "0da665ab5653",
    "level": 30,
    "method": "PUT",
    "msg": "REQ: 401 PUT /api/xxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "rocket",
    "pid": 10,
    "reqHeaders": {
        "accept-encoding": "gzip",
        "cloudfront-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer": "true",
        "cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer": "false",
        "cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer": "false",
        "cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer": "false",
        "cloudfront-viewer-country": "XX",
        "content-length": "74",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "host": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "user-agent": "okhttp/3.10.0",
        "via": "2.0 28b8fcaccf73021230d8e4a6c3d9e81e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "x-amz-cf-id": "UqaCCZL9XDze9baJM5dq1fexhqaX9_Qurg2i88A3m-pfrK68Bx93mg==",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5de37d7b-9e9d1ee0ad828a4e316b4f5c",
        "x-forwarded-for": "70.31.103.92, 64.252.147.153",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "x-newrelic-id": "VgYOV1RaDRADU1RUBwgFUVA=",
        "x-request-id": "Root=1-5de37d7b-9e9d1ee0ad828a4e316b4f5c"
    },
    "reqTime": "2019-12-01T08:44:43.955Z",
    "req_id": "Root=1-5de37d7b-9e9d1ee0ad828a4e316b4f5c",
    "resMs": 1,
    "route": "/api/xxxxxxxxxx",
    "routeName": "putapixxxxxxxxxx",
    "status": 401,
    "time": "2019-12-01T08:44:43.956Z",
    "url": "/api/xxxxxxxxxx",
    "v": 0
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example log line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself

```
fields @timestamp, status, err, method, url, req_id
| parse @message '"x-forwarded-for":"*"' as ip
| filter status >= 400
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 10
```

Comment: You can also use backticks to escape special characters so you can do:


`filter \`x-forwarded-for\` = "*"`

Comment: This is just a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 29):

put it in between a back-tick: `` ` ``

```
fields @timestamp, status, err, method, url, req_id, `x-forwarded-for`
```

Comment: Sometimes, it might be `\`headers.X-Forwarded-For.0\``